# Как работают константы в c++

Tags: c++, const

У меня возник вопрос по работе констант. Ключевое слово `const` действует только во время компиляции, под этим я подразумеваю то, что в последствии, во время выполнения, например при помощи `WriteProcessMemory` из другой программы мы сможем изменить данную "константу" и записать в нее другое значение. Или же такие данные записываются в реальную неизменяемую память(если такая есть) и их нельзя будет изменить вообще?

Comment: Вам надо нарушить константность или оставаться в рамках правил игры? Формально `const` означает гарантию неизменности (кроме момента инициализации) во время выполнения.

Comment: @Harry. нет. Просто интересно, что да как. Тогда получается, что если константы не оптимизируются компилятором, то они хранятся в особой неизменяемой памяти, которую вообще нельзя поменять?

Comment: В принципе, во многих случаях они могут вообще нигде не храниться, на сколько знаю. Компилятор анализирует код, и если не находит необходимости выделения места в памяти, то может запихнуть константу прямо в код в то место, где есть  обращения к ней. По крайней мере, для числовых констант, как понимаю, это так. Для строковых, (и, вероятно, каких-то сложных структур данных) кажется, это не применимо.

Comment: Не обязательно, но вполне возможно. Главное - обеспечить неизменность значения во время выполнения программы, а уж как именно - это дело компилятора и его разработчика :)

Comment: "переписать константу в памяти" можно, вот только компилятор на это не рассчитывает и может так оказаться, что в памяти значение висит одно, а используется по факту другое, потому что компилятор в каком то конкретном случае решил использовать заранее припасенное значение. Можно пометить константу ещё и volatile, тогда оно будет лучше работать, но нужно ли это? Но есть и законные случаи, как передача по ссылке на константу - там значение хоть и "константное", но может легко менятся.